# Angularjs reset form field with type of email

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJs it seems that when you try to 'reset' a form, by setting all of the models to an empty object, if an input is `type="email"` this doesn't get cleared.  Changing it to `type="text"` works however, but then you lose the red border on validation.

Is there anyway to reset or clear an email type input?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the button type="reset"? http://plnkr.co/edit/WhzQw3yitmOx9WM6YuFh?p=preview

Comment: I'm clearing in the markup, I'm clearing on a different `ng-click` and do `$scope.myModels = {};`

Comment: I updated the plunker with another button with an ng-click to trigger a function that simply do `$scope.item = {}` and it works.

Comment: @jpmorin the "Other" button still doesn't seem to clear out the email field.   But, I did find I could combine both type="reset" and my own onClick event, which seems to work.  Do you want to answer this question and I'll select you? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure why it does not work. I ran the plunker demo both in Chrome and Firefox and I had no problem.

Comment: I just tried in IE10 and it still worked. Did the plunker work for you too?

Comment: Ah, I see the difference.  If I enter an invalid email address, it won't clear that.  Only once the validation has been complete.

Comment: The type="reset" button works even if the email is invalid, but the other button works only if the validation is completed like your said.

Comment: @jpmorin, right, so ideally the click action would act the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, refer to the OP comments for explainations and see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WhzQw3yitmOx9WM6YuFh?p=preview) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

In my case , when using a validation form button binded to the scope with `ng-disabled` directive, I had to use double reset logic :

```
<form>
    <input type="email" ng-model="formdata.email" />
    <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" type="reset" ng-click="formdata = {}">Clear</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" />
</form>
```

- `type="reset"` : in order to clear the field even when an invalid email is currently filling the field (without this attribute, an invalid email isn't removed by the `ng-click`)
- `ng-click="formdata = {}"` : reinitialize all scope bindings. Without that, when reseting form, the ng-disabled won't update and the validate button will still be enabled after reset ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that until email field is valid, model is not binded yet. So when you do `myModel = {}`, the text field is keeping its invalid email. However if you do `myModel.Email = ''` this will clean the text field