# Email field does not reset in Angular documentation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms
2. Scroll to **Binding to form and control state**.

If you click the reset button, it fires off this:

```
$scope.reset = function(form) {
    if (form) {
      form.$setPristine();
      form.$setUntouched();
    }
    $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
  };
```

But when you click the Reset button, the E-mail field of the form does not clear.

I'm following the documentation and having the same problem in my own code. Not sure if it's a bug.

Comment: seems like reset only works if you provide valid email address

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't been following documentation as close. Paragraph below form:

> Note that novalidate is used to disable browser's native form
>   validation.
>
> The value of ngModel won't be set unless it passes validation for the
>   input field. For example: inputs of type email must have a value in
>   the form of user@domain.

No worries, it happens to all of us - I also always glance through documentation ;)

EDIT: See these links also

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10027

[Angularjs reset form field with type of email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114612/angularjs-reset-form-field-with-type-of-email)

Comment: Shouldn't a reset button reset everything though, including fields that don't pass validation?